# Is there a way to display a pgfplots defined function as an equation?

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I have in my preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{
        compat=newest,
        /pgf/declare function={
            g(\x) = -x^4+2*x^3-x-2;
        },
    }
```

and then later in the body I have a plot of the function g(x).
I would like to be able to reference g(x) outside of a pgfplots environment, and have it show up as the defined expression.

Something like `$g(x)=\pgfdisplay{g(\x)}$`
and have it render the same way `$g(x)=-x^4+2*x^3-x-2$` would render.